# Copy paste zip file between Host (windows 7) and Oracle virtual box (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS)

Tags: 14.04

how to do copy paste or share files between host and my oracle vm linux box.
I tried Drag and Drop bidirectional option - > but from oracle machine to my host when i do drag drop, my vm adonded.. i have to manually start again.

I created shared location in windows and added under shared folders list with automount and make permanent enabled. Nothing worked for me..

Am very new to ubuntu and linux. please suggest. 
-siva

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php). It's a free SFTP, SCP and FTP GUI-based client for Windows, which lets you drag and drop files via an SSH-connection. Therefore you just need the tool on your Windows computer and a running SSH-Server on your Ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a shared foler open an explorer window in the virtualbox.

Type `\\vboxsrv\` into the path field and press enter.

Now, you should see all shared folders.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, VirtualBox does not support file sharing via clipboard sharing or drag 'n drop. Although if the virtual machine has its "Guest Additions" installed, you can use [shared folders](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15868).

Keep in mind if you use Bridge or Host Only Adapter (not NAT) for your VM, you can do this by yourself. Share a folder in your windows machine and use `samba` to reach it via the Linux machine.